# Проблема с общими документами в 1с битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Делали бэкап, восстановили бэкап, битрикс успешно встал, но при переходе по ссылке общие документы открывается пустая страница (меню есть шапка есть, просто пустая), в админ панели при переходе в КонтентОбщие документы-файлы, все pdf файлы есть на месте и подпапки тоже.Но опять же таки если перейти в подпапку тоже показывает нет данных, просто пусто, а если нажать файлы то виден список pdf файлов.

Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Вопрос непонятный. Речь о стандартном функционале Битрикса или каком-то модуле? Или вообще об инфоблоке?

Покажите скриншоты и/или адреса, куда, собственно, переходите щелкая `КонтентОбщие` (у меня, например, в Битриксе есть только `Файлы и папки`)

Comment: Редакция корпоротивный портал.А как сюда загрузить скриншоты?Может удобнее показать в скайпе?Может поможете?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/ вот, например. Устанавливайте приложение и делайте скриншот. Или делайте скрин и заливайте и потом ссылку сюда.

Comment: На главной странице есть виджет http://prntscr.com/969sxr последние добавленные документы, при переходе на один из документов http://prntscr.com/969t4y   Хотя все документы через админку можно найти и открыть http://prntscr.com/969t8b

Comment: А как выглядит точная ссылка на документ? Которая не работает?
Есть легкое подозрение, что дело в киррилических именах файлов.

Comment: Ну так до этого всё работало ведь...Скопировали папку битрикса, слили дамп, и поставили на сервер, то есть залили папку и поставили дамп.Настройки всё прописаны и вот началось это всё чудо....Раньше открывались подпапки и документы а сейчас пусто по ссылке /docs/Приказы/по%20основной%20деятельности

Comment: А в поддержку Битрикса пробовали писать?